# Storing data received as unicode as a zip file

Tags: python, zip, web-deployment, plotly-dash

I am developing a website using dash. My users have to submit a zipped file as the original (csv) file size is huge. I am using the standard upload mechanism suggested by dash here https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload. list_of_contents is the data received in the function `update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)` and is unicode. I wonder how can I store that data as a zip file on my server just like the one submitted by the users.

If storing it as zip isn't possible, what else can be done to store the file in a conveniently retrievable way?

Comment: What's stopping you from uploading the `.zip` files directly on the server?

Comment: file mode is "rb"/"wb" with `ascii` encoding, need convert to ascii before saving.